# Error checking for Selenium in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I have this block of code that is supposed to check if an element is on the page, if it is it should out put the given message. If it's not, it's supposed to output the error message. I can't get this to check my elements correctly. Should I create an object or an array? If so, how do I check multiple values within those?

```
var e1 = 'search';
var e2 = 'success';

driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className(e1, e2)).then(function(webElement) {
    console.log('The elements ' +
                '"' + e1 + '",' +
                '"' + e2 + '"' + 'are present.');

}, function(err) {
    if (err.state && err.state === 'no such element') {
        console.log('The element ' + '"' + e1 + '"' + ' is NOT found.');
    } else {
        webdriver.promise.rejected(err);
    }
});
```

EDIT: Using Wilsons code

```
var destinationStarlet = 'log';

var URL = 'http://localhost:8888/' + destinationStarlet;

var a = '.nav';
getElementByCss(URL, driver, a, onResult);

var b = '.advanced-search';
getElementByCss(URL, driver, b, onResult);


function onResult(err, element) {
if (err) {
    return console.log(err.message);
}

element.getText()
    .then(

function (presentText) {

});
}

driver.sleep(10000);

function getElementByCss(URL, driver, css, cb) {
function error(err) {
    if (err.name === 'NoSuchElementError') {
        err.message = 'The element "' + css + '" was NOT found.';
    }

    cb(err);
}

function elementFound(element) {
     console.log('The element ' + '"' + css + '"' + ' is present!');

    cb(null, element);
}

function siteLoaded() {
    driver.findElement({
        css: css
    })
        .then(elementFound, error);
}

driver.get(URL)
    .then(siteLoaded)
}
```

Comment: What's the point of your edit? If it is a solution, then it should be posted as an answer, not as an edit to your question. If what you mean is that even after using Wilson's code, you still have problems (and your comment on your edit suggests this is what you mean), then please be clear about what the problem is exactly. What error are you getting? What fails to happen? (Also, if Wilson's answer did not solve your problem you really should unaccept it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose we are inspecting this HTML

[image]

And we want to know if the buttons inside the div.buttons exist:

```
var URL = 'http://some-web-site';

var myButtonCSS = '.buttons #my-button';
var myAnotherButtonCSS = '.buttons #my-another-button';
var myThirdButtonCSS = '.buttons #my-third-button';

getElementByCss(URL, driver, myButtonCSS, onResult); // exist
getElementByCss(URL, driver, myAnotherButtonCSS, onResult); // exist
getElementByCss(URL, driver, myThirdButtonCSS, onResult); // does not exist

function onResult (err, element) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err.message);
  }

  element
    .getText()
    .then(
      function (buttonText) {
        console.log(buttonText);
      }
    );
}
```

I created an utility function that will allow you to search for an element by css:

```
function getElementByCss (URL, driver, css, cb) {
    function error (err) {
      if (err.name === 'NoSuchElementError') {
        err.message = 'Element at "' + css + '", was not found.';
      }

      cb(err);
    }

    function elementFound (element) {
      cb(null, element);
    }

    function siteLoaded () {
      driver
        .findElement({
          css: css
        })
        .then(elementFound, error);
    }

    driver
      .get(URL)
      .then(siteLoaded)
}
```

Comment: I've only gotten this to somewhat work. Some elements say they are present and some don't. Does it have to do with them having child/being a parent of an element? Any clues?

Comment: probably your CSS selector is the problem, one way to debug this part is testing the CSS selector you are providing to jQuery.

Comment: or perhaps you can provide me here the HTML and CSS selector you are using

Comment: Updated in my original post.

Comment: can you provide the html you are using? you can use the https://gist.github.com/ for showing the html code.